# Saving requests made during Cypress test as curls

Tags: cypress

Is it possible to save requests made during Cypress test as curls to be reviewed later? E.g. for importing them in Postman.

Network tab, of DevTools of Cypress application, logs request from Cypress app, not from application under test itself.

Answer (score 0):

The network tab will show requests from the AUT, but if you want to find all the requests use `intercept`

```js
const requests = []
cy.intercept('/api/*', (request) => {
  console.log(request.url)            // get them from the console
  requests.push(request.url)          // or save them to a file at end of spec
})

...

after(() => {
  cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/requests.json', requests)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To gain detailed information about the request and response including the response time, you can utilize the HAR file format (http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/har-12-spec/).  To generate a HAR file on the fly during the execution of your Cypress tests you can use the [cypress-har-generator](https://github.com/NeuraLegion/cypress-har-generator).

```js
describe('my tests', () => {
  before(() => {
    // start recording
    cy.recordHar();
  });

  after(() => {
    // save the HAR file
    cy.saveHar({ waitForIdle: true });
  });

  it('does something', () => {
    cy.visit('https://example.com');

    // ...
  });
});
```

This plugin will generate a HAR file that can be imported to the network panel of developer tools (https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-76/#HAR) or Postman (https://blog.postman.com/postman-now-supports-importing-har-files/), for further analysis.